# Working with OLEDB ? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In we application, i am trying to access the excel sheet, when i am accessing .xls it is fine, but when i am using .xlsx then it is giving error like:

```
 Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered
```

Can you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error appears when Microsoft Office 2007 is not installed and you use.xlsx file.

Check on your server, where your website is hosted, that Office 2007 is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.
download it from [Microsoft access database engine](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255)

Check once